# Prevent checking a checkbox after onclick

Tags: javascript, checkbox

How can I prevent that a checkbox gets checked (without the use of `disable`)?

I tried

```
function nocheck() {
   if(somevar.value>3){  
        alert("Not allowed");  
        document.getElementById('mybox').checked = false;           
   }
};
```

with

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox" id="mybox" value="test" onclick="nocheck();" />
```

But this way the checkbox still gets checked after the alert message pops up.

EDIT:
Thanks to the comments/answers, I was able to come closer to a solution but not yet solved the problem - what's wrong with this code? http://jsfiddle.net/9kS8E/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ez-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox" id="mybox" value="test" onclick="nocheck();" class="ez-hide">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var user = { premium : false };
function nocheck() {
    if(!user.premium){                             
     return false;
    } else {   
     return true;
   };
};
```

Comment: if you don't want to allow a checkbox to be checked then you should use `disabled='disabled'` attribute in the checkbox.

Comment: every user should be able to check it, but only for premium users the status `checked` should remain. for others, the checkbox should uncheck again.

Comment: agree with OP question ,this question is geniune

Comment: updated my code: http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/rQG3r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) save value of check box in a variable [ while "click" value of checkbox will get changed ]

(2) check user type,

- if not a premium user, toggle value of check box.
- else no need to change value of checkbox

(*) by using toggle : checkbox is already checked or not, we are not allowing a normal user to check it.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/rQG3r/

```
       <input type="checkbox" name="mybox" id="mybox" value="test" onclick="noCheck(event)" />

        var user = { premium : true };
        function nocheck(elem) {
           var newValue = elem.checked;
           if(!user.premium) {                             
         alert("not allowed");
             elem.checked = !newValue;// toggle value
           } else {
             alert(" allowed ");
           }   
        };
```

Comment: this comes close and works as expected but I want to be able to uncheck a checkbox no matter whether the user is a premium user. Your example does not make a difference between checking and unchecking.

Answer (score 3):

i think  i not understand your question but i think you are searching this,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox" id="mybox" value="test" onclick="return false;" />
```

OR

html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox" id="mybox" value="test" onclick="nocheck()" />
```

js

```
function nocheck() {
   if(somevar.value>3){  
        alert("Not allowed");  
        return false;
   }else
        return true;
};
```

Comment: we can use event.preventDefault(), but this is a fine approach. return false

Comment: to make things more clear, the `if` statement is not always true

Comment: but the whole thing is wrong. if we don't want to allow checking a checkbox then disabling it is the correct thing, I think

Comment: Imagine a user clicks a checkbox but checking it is only allowed for 'premium' users. So you want them to check it, get a notification, and uncheck it again

Comment: so there is no way to uncheck a checkbox after it has been checked?

Comment: @SPi you can `return false;` from your method according to your need

Answer (score -1):

Your code should also work.
It's getting unchecked after alert.
You can say alert after unchecking like this.

`if(somevar.value>3){ 
    document.getElementById('mybox').checked = false;
    alert("Not allowed"); 
}`